# Could a specific website be blocked or throttled for all users by Verizon

Tags: web-hosting, performance, mobile, cdn, networking

UPDATE:

The issue was in fact a Verizon "routing" issue. I reached out to Verizon and was given the go around, so I contacted my host who did some testing. We used Nord VPN to mask the traffic and performance instantly improved. We still working on trying to get Verizon to do something at a snails pace, but found a work around for the users affected who wanted to stay Verizon. A majority of users just switched to AT&T or another carrier.

----------------------------------------------------------------I'm having an interesting issue that I haven't experienced before. I have a small app that uses only small amounts of data. A couple clients contacted me saying that their users were experiencing slow downs that progressed all the way to the website not responding after all after about 10 minutes of use on their mobile phones.

I couldn't reproduce the issue, and contacted over a hundred other clients and could not find anyone else with the same issue.

After back and forth with them I determined that the issue affects all phone from older and newer android to older and newer iPhones. After about a week of this happening, and  being unable to determine or even produce an issue a customer stated they hate Verizon because alot of their sites do the same thing. I contacted each site experiencing the issue... All of them are Verizon.

I contacted many of the customers without issue, and all are on ATT or Us Cellular or Spectrum. None were on Verizon.

Is this possible? Could Verizon be throttling my website or doing something that other carriers are not? I instructed my customers to buy a cheap at&t go phone and try it, and it works flawlessly.

If Verizon is doing this, how do I avoid it? We are a safety app for daycares...so it is very surprising that we would be throttled or limited, but they may not know and it could be some automated system...Or do you think I am completely off base and it is something else?

Comment: This is why we need net neutrality.   >:(

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I updated the question with the latest information. Your absolutely right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely possible for Verizon to do this.

The rest if this answer can only be speculation -

Especially if you are using HTTPS , and your site is "not dodgy" look at your hosting provider. It is possible that they are hosting dodgy content and Verizon is limiting access to the location by IP address/range, and your site is an innocent casualty.

It is also possible there is a routing issue between your provider (or an upstream) and Verizon.

Practically speaking ( In either case there is not much you can do other then shift hosting or get your provider to fix/work around the issue. (Theoretically you may be able to set up a VPN system with your clients or get Verizon to listen to you - but I don't consider these realistic solutions in the typical small-business / non-techie user case)

Comment: How about using a CDN?  That might help.

Comment: Thank you for the information - We use dedicated Rackspace, with HTTPS on a high level cert, I wouldn't think we would be considered dodgy, but it is possible we are being limited, or more likely there being a routing issue. I may have a client put a VPN like Nord on their phones to test if the issue gets resolved... you are right that isn't realistic solution, but part of the troubleshooting step.